# asynchronous typescript to synchronous typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
postPersonalDetails(pdData){
let options : RequestOptionsArgs;
let token:string;
let id:string;
this.getToken().then((val) => {
  token = val;
  console.log("I am in token func"+token);
});
this.storage.get('userID').then((val) => {
  id = val;
  console.log(val);
});
console.log("I amhere"+token+id);
```

I am getting the data in 1st consoleLog and 2nd Consolelog

Because of the asynchronous nature 3rd console log is printing first
there by I am getting token is undefined and user ID is undefined
What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Use [async/await](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/async-await.html). Or you may use Promise.all method

Comment: I am using Ionic3/Angular 4/ typescript. I am getting compile error with async/await

Comment: @vivek https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6SH72uAn3Q - Promise all example appears around 12:14.. .There's a JsFiddle for part of the code a bit before that.. http://jsfiddle.net/jspatel/mkjh2ev5/

Answer (score 3):

The angular setup comes with `core-js` and a polyfill for `Promise`. You can combine your promises with `Promise.all` ([see MDN with a detailed method explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)) and then proceed once both promises are resolved.

```
Promise.all([
  promise1, promise2, ...
])
```

Keep in mind that `Promise.all` rejects if one of the combined promises is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more details on what PerfectPixel proposed.

```
const promise1 = this.getToken().then((val) => {
  console.log("I am in token func"+val);
  return val;
});

const promise2 = this.storage.get('userID').then((val) => {
  console.log(val);
  return val;
});

Promise
  .all([promise1, promise2])
  .then((results) => {
    const [ token, id ] = results;
    console.log("I am here"+token+id);
  });
}
```

Here is a more general example of it working. (See Bergi's comments for more detail on side-effects.)

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve("the-token").then((val) => {
  console.log("I am in token func: " + val);
  return val;
});

const promise2 = Promise.resolve("the-userID").then((val) => {
  console.log("I am in id func: " + val);
  return val;
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then((results) => {
  const [ token, id ] = results;
  console.log("I am here: " + token + " " + id);
});
```

Comment: Don't use those global variables. Please.

Comment: @Bergi Good point. Is the edit to the answer sufficient to allay the concern?

Comment: No. They're still free variables (in the callback where they are used) initialised at arbitrary points. Don't use variables at all - use the promise result values!

Comment: Yes, the second edit did it. Now just remove the horrible version from your answer completely - the OP never intended to do this.

Comment: @downvoter Could you please provide more information about your downvote or suggest improvements. I would appreciate that.